# Package "StanPackage" has failed to load properly while opening a VC++ soln in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, package

[image]

As can be seen in the above snapshot, I am getting the Package load failure error, when I try to open a VC++ solution in VS2008. Why is it that the "Stanpackage" is failing to load ? What is this package?

PS:: I installed VS recently by uninstalling the older one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See [Visual Studio 2008 Package Load Failure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joy/archive/2009/06/23/visual-studio-2008-package-load-failure.aspx)

You may use 'devenv /resetskippkgs' to re-enable package loading.

**Solution 1:** Use visual studio command line to reset or reinstall the
packages.

**Step 1:** Open [Windows Start] / [All Programs] / [Microsoft Visual Studio
2008] /  [Visual Studio Tools] / [Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt]. If
you are in Vista, please right click it and select "Run as administrator"

**Step 2:** Type "devenv /ResetSkipPkgs". This command will re-enable the
loading of the VSPackage.

**Step 3:** Restart Visual Studio IDE and try to create workflow project again.

**Step 4:** If it still fails, type "devenv /Setup". This command will
re-install all the VSPackages.

**Step 5:** Restart Visual Studio IDE and try to create workflow project again.

For more info follow [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1720301.aspx/1).